# Need java code in importing a text file comparing a set of strings

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, java-io

I have a set strings (string1,string2,string3,string4) and i want to search this in a text file (input.txt) using java coding, i have tried using below command but it is not working, please help.

```
package string;
import java.io.File; //Required for input file
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; //Required for exceptioenter code heren throw
import java.util.Scanner; //required for scanner

public class strng {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException // throws clause added
{

//ask the the for the string to be searched
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter part of the string: ");
    String searchString = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

 // open the data file
    File file = new File("APPD_01_15_16_01.txt");
 // create a scanner from the file
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);



    // While there is another line to read.
    while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        // read the lines
         //Read string

        //Check if user input is a match and if true print out info.

        if(searchString.contains("samplemachine")
        {
            System.out.println("Yup!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Fail!");
        }
    }

    // be polite and close the file
    inputFile.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Where is your reading of string from your inputFile?

Comment: Your example code is a little confusing, because you seem to be comparing the users keyboard input with the string your searching for "samplemachine" and not the input from the file.

Comment: i have tried searching from user input, but my requirement is to search from the set of string

Comment: *but it is not working* is not a good enough explanation

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your file? That would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing what you are saying you want to do. If your requirement  is to is to search from the set of string then why are you comparing with the input taken from user?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this will do what you are looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException //Alternatively, you should probably handle this.
{
    //I don't know what your source is for the search strings,
    //but this will simulate them.
    String[] toSearch = {"Strings", "to", "search", "for."};
    //Simplest way to read a file when no editing is needed.
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("input.txt")))
    {
        for (String str : toSearch)
        {
            //Simplest way to check if one String contains another.
            if (line.contains(str))
            {
                System.out.println("Yup!");
                //Now that we know the file contains a String, no need to continue.
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    //If it even gets to this point, it got through the file with no match.
    System.out.println("Fail!");
}
```

Some of the other answers touched on similar methods, but I felt mine was more complete in covering the whole question rather than specific portions of it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, your not reading the contents of your inputFile. You should read the contents of your inputFile line by line inside your loop. After you read the line, you can now check if the line contains what your looking for.

```
// While there is another line to read.
while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
{
    // read the next line from the input file
    String line = inputFile.nextLine();

    //Check if user input is a match and if true print out info.
    if(line.contains(searchString)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```